# The UIlabel AttributedString first line indentation

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

1. label text first line need to indent，I use `NSMutableParagraphStyle` `setFirstLineHeadIndent`.
2. But when the label is only one line, AttributedString intercept omitted behind a few characters,why?

   ```
   NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
   [style setFirstLineHeadIndent:11];
   [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abcdefg" attributes:dic];
   ```

Comment: Try to also do `[style setHeadIndent:11];`.

Comment: I tried, but I demand is: Only the first line of the space, the overall characters with no Spaces